# this.props is undefined inside a class

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux

I am creating a chat app using Firebase and React-Native. Now I am trying to change the reference to Firebase DataBase dynamically. But I could not access state inside a class. Where the error states this.props is undefined.

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Fire {
    constructor() {
        this.init();
        this.observeAuth();
    }

    init = () =>
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: 'AIzaSyBN7GqrGYOyhykm26wyRpXYNe0LBx6wrec',
            authDomain: 'kc-connect.firebaseapp.com',
            databaseURL: 'https://kc-connect.firebaseio.com',
            projectId: 'kc-connect',
            storageBucket: '',
            messagingSenderId: '526601747673',
            appId: "1:526601747673:web:f510e43766eb970c"
        });

    observeAuth = () => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged);
    }

    onAuthStateChanged = user => {
        if (!user) {
            try {
                console.log('user', user);
                firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
            } catch ({ message }) {
                console.log('user', user);
                alert(message);
            }
        }
    };

    get uid() {
        return (firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid;
    }

    get ref() {
        return firebase.database().ref('messages/' + this.props.userInfo.id);
    }

    parse = snapshot => {
        const { timestamp: numberStamp, text, user } = snapshot.val();
        const { key: _id } = snapshot;
        const timestamp = new Date(numberStamp);
        const message = {
            _id,
            timestamp,
            text,
            user,
        };
        console.log(message);
        return message;
    };

    on = callback =>
        this.ref
        .limitToLast(20)
        .on('child_added', snapshot => callback(this.parse(snapshot)));

    get timestamp() {
        return firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
    }
    // send the message to the Backend
    send = messages => {
        for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            const { text, user } = messages[i];
            const message = {
                text,
                user,
                timestamp: this.timestamp
            };
            console.log(message);
            this.append(message);
        }
    };

    append = message => this.ref.push(message);

    // close the connection to the Backend
    off() {
        this.ref.off();
    }
}

Fire.shared = new Fire();

mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        userInfo: state.auth.userInfo
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Fire);
```

Here in get ref function I am not able to access the state using this.props.userInfo.id. How will I do it?

Answer (score 1):

To define a React component class, you need to extend React.Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native

class Welcome extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Text>Hello, {this.props.name}</Text>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not see react imported in you Fire class

Try this Step to Fix:

1. You need to import react on top of class.

```
import React from 'react';
```

2. Extend React in Fire class.

```
class Fire extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return 
   }
}
```